# How to redirect back to a page when wrong file type has been uploaded via multer in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, zip, pug, multer

Im trying to handle if the wrong file type is uploaded via multer to redirect back to the main page with an error message stored in a passed variable.

In the fillFilter of the upload const, I've tried to redirect to the page using app.post but that doesn't work. I tried to handle the callback error in the post response but it did the same thing. Again I can't see much documentation on what I require so it's hard to figure out if the syntax i did could cause an issue.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {fileSize: 25000000}, //works with bytes, created a 25MB limit
    fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
        console.log(file.originalname)
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        if(ext !== '.zip') {
            return callback(new Error('Only Zips are allowed'))
            //Need to modify this to redirect?
        }
        callback(null, true) 
    }
}) 

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render("index");
})

app.post('/', upload.single('fileUpload'), function (req, res) {
        res.render("index", {postStatus : "File Succesfully Uploaded"}); 
});
```

If the correct format gets put in, in this case a zip, it should redirect back to the index page with a status message saying, File Successfully Uploaded, and is stored in the uploads folder.

If its anything else, it redirects back to the main page but with an error message saying File Type not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You should return a call back in upload and then check it in route. From there you could do the redirect. Below code can`t be copy and pasted . It just express the way function should be implemented. 
EX:

```
const upload = function(storage, callback) {
  multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 25000000 }, //works with bytes, created a 25MB limit
    fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
      console.log(file.originalname);
      let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
      if (ext !== '.zip') {
        return callback(new Error('Invalid File Type ' + username));
      }
      callback(null, true);
    }
  });
};

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
//Check call back here
//if error do the redirect with error message

//else
  res.render('index', { postStatus: 'File Succesfully Uploaded' });
});
```